# Port forward Devstack tried to connect to local IP instead of IP address of port forwarding in Swift

Tags: java, networking, openstack-swift, jclouds, keystone

I installed Devstack in one of the VMs inside the network with IP address 192.168.89.51 but I port forwarded of port 5000 into seclab.*.*.de:50071. The authentication in Keystone is successful and I was able to get the token from Keystone but when I tried to create a container in Swift, Devstack is trying to access the local IP address instead of the IP of the port forwarded of port 8080 and I am not sure is it possible to specify where Swift supposed to connect after successfully logged in from Keystone.

Here is my code:

```
package testopenstack;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.io.Closeables;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder;
import org.jclouds.io.Payload;
import org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config.SLF4JLoggingModule;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.domain.Container;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ObjectApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.PutOptions;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.google.common.io.ByteSource.wrap;
import static org.jclouds.io.Payloads.newByteSourcePayload;

public class JCloudsSwift implements Closeable {
   public static final String CONTAINER_NAME = "jclouds-example";
   public static final String OBJECT_NAME = "jclouds-example.txt";

   private SwiftApi swiftApi;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      JCloudsSwift jcloudsSwift = new JCloudsSwift();

      try {
         jcloudsSwift.createContainer();
         jcloudsSwift.uploadObjectFromString();
         jcloudsSwift.listContainers();
         jcloudsSwift.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         jcloudsSwift.close();
      }
   }

   public JCloudsSwift() {
      Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module>of(
            new SLF4JLoggingModule());

      String provider = "openstack-swift";
      String identity = "admin:admin"; // tenantName:userName
      String credential = "stack";

      swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint("http://seclab.*.*.de:50071/v2.0/")
            .credentials(identity, credential)
            .modules(modules)
            .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);
      System.out.println("hello");
   }

   private void createContainer() {
      System.out.println("Create Container");

      ContainerApi containerApi = swiftApi.getContainerApi("RegionOne");
      CreateContainerOptions options = CreateContainerOptions.Builder
            .metadata(ImmutableMap.of(
                  "key1", "value1",
                  "key2", "value2"));

      containerApi.create(CONTAINER_NAME, options);

      System.out.println("  " + CONTAINER_NAME);
   }

   private void uploadObjectFromString() {
      System.out.println("Upload Object From String");

      ObjectApi objectApi = swiftApi.getObjectApi("RegionOne", CONTAINER_NAME);
      Payload payload = newByteSourcePayload(wrap("Hello World".getBytes()));

      objectApi.put(OBJECT_NAME, payload, PutOptions.Builder.metadata(ImmutableMap.of("key1", "value1")));

      System.out.println("  " + OBJECT_NAME);
   }

   private void listContainers() {
      System.out.println("List Containers");

      ContainerApi containerApi = swiftApi.getContainerApi("RegionOne");
      Set<Container> containers = containerApi.list().toSet();

      for (Container container : containers) {
         System.out.println("  " + container);
      }
   }

   public void close() throws IOException {
      Closeables.close(swiftApi, true);
   }
}
```

And here is the output of the console:

```
hello
Create Container
14:34:46.704 [main] DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials
14:34:46.707 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -520408508: POST http://seclab.*.*.de:50071/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
14:34:46.707 [main] DEBUG jclouds.wire - >> "Sensitive data in payload, use jclouds.wire.log.sensitive override to enable logging this data."
14:34:46.707 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> POST http://seclab.*.*.de:50071/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
14:34:46.707 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:34:46.707 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json
14:34:46.708 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Content-Length: 93
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Receiving response -520408508: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << x-openstack-request-id: req-57a2d719-d36e-46ae-afd8-14a9bb99016a
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Vary: X-Auth-Token
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 12:34:44 GMT
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Type: application/json
14:34:47.125 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Length: 4031
14:34:47.147 [main] DEBUG jclouds.wire - << "{"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2017-05-09T12:34:45.000000Z", "expires": "2017-05-09T13:34:45.000000Z", "id": "gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ", "tenant": {"description": "Bootstrap project for initializing the cloud.", "enabled": true, "id": "6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "name": "admin"}, "audit_ids": ["Kiz1yvu2Tfu5xULiBRa6gA"]}, "serviceCatalog": [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2.1", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2.1", "id": "29db5ee9c13140d0a6d2dd72cae12151", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2.1"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9696/", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9696/", "id": "10dc7bac93124c42bf2bd168a1416e0c", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9696/"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "network", "name": "neutron"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "id": "02e0b2f13379462d90abf45ef3c8b364", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volumev2", "name": "cinderv2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v3/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v3/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "id": "84d50ee86e074bbfafcb7046ac231aa4", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v3/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volumev3", "name": "cinderv3"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9292", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9292", "id": "3e64c156de154a3c927bc05cd9de1204", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:9292"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "id": "6f42e5d5473a4ba09ba9f6450c64a501", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8774/v2/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute_legacy", "name": "nova_legacy"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v1/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v1/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "id": "c9ef88deedc94faf9d85a43ffbcbcd22", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8776/v1/6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8080", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c", "id": "a42c9c01cd284b79800511303c6a440f", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "object-store", "name": "swift"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51/placement", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51/placement", "id": "7d1abfcfc5384486982ae201bd7c11fc", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51/placement"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "placement", "name": "placement"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://192.168.89.51/identity_admin", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://192.168.89.51/identity", "id": "682526cf22c1478387a8059ce30a14c8", "publicURL": "http://192.168.89.51/identity"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}], "user": {"username": "admin", "roles_links": [], "id": "7887bab1a7b64d34a7e9994a40b672b1", "roles": [{"name": "admin"}], "name": "admin"}, "metadata": {"is_admin": 0, "roles": ["b358d0d61ab847148412403b862d64ea"]}}}"
14:34:47.188 [main] DEBUG o.j.o.k.v.s.RegionIdToURIFromAccessForTypeAndVersion - endpoints for apiType object-store and version 1: {RegionOne=[Endpoint{id=a42c9c01cd284b79800511303c6a440f, region=RegionOne, publicURL=http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c, internalURL=http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c, adminURL=http://192.168.89.51:8080}]}
14:34:47.208 [main] DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking container:create
14:34:47.208 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:34:47.208 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:34:47.208 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:34:47.209 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:34:47.209 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:34:47.209 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:35:50.228 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 1/5: delaying for 50 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:35:50.278 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:36:53.310 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 2/5: delaying for 218 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
14:36:53.528 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:36:53.528 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:36:53.528 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:36:53.528 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:36:53.529 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:36:53.529 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:37:56.545 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 3/5: delaying for 494 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:37:57.040 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:39:00.064 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 4/5: delaying for 500 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
14:39:00.564 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:39:00.565 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:39:00.565 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:39:00.565 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:39:00.565 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:39:00.565 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:40:03.574 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 5/5: delaying for 500 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1467868091: PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key1: value1
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Container-Meta-key2: value2
14:40:04.075 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABZEbdlOHhMXsuiEaygyPOFqyjZcxT5QbPHUDGfNQ6wLDceDF6SkcYiuamSnWwpkVCbXWqNEdZanRgKuErXtl_aSMScNudvqxEFP0DfQtUw6RW_IDFwy0BSiXuygHYbGarcQvsmSj8CcDnyiWx9ojg3ugK8y-RWGnM3nSLQtokbbAgWXKQ
14:41:07.088 [main] ERROR o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Cannot retry after server error, command has exceeded retry limit 5: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.public abstract boolean org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi.create(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.options.CreateContainerOptions)[jclouds-example, CreateContainerOptions{formParameters={}, headers={X-Container-Meta-key1=[value1], X-Container-Meta-key2=[value2]}, queryParameters={}}], request=PUT http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c/jclouds-example HTTP/1.1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jclouds will connect to the different OpenStack services by using the endpoints provided in the service catalog. It will try first the public URL and fallback to the private one, if missing. This is the Swift endpoint of your environment as it appears in the Keystone service catalog:

```
{
    "endpoints": [{
        "adminURL":"http://192.168.89.51:8080",
        "region":"RegionOne",
        "internalURL":"http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c",
        "id":"a42c9c01cd284b79800511303c6a440f",
        "publicURL":"http://192.168.89.51:8080/v1/AUTH_6a99ddd4ea79417ab1b924cf8aee3e8c"
    }],
    "endpoints_links":[ ],
    "type":"object-store",
    "name":"swift"
}
```

The problem here is that Keystone is returning the internal URL for the public and internal endpoints, and that's why jclouds uses it. You need to configure your OpenStack installation (Keystone) to properly return your Swift address with the forwarded port in the service catalog.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to make sure that after authentication in Keystone it will return the port forwarded address of Swift but I still couldn't find it how. Do you have any idea?